# Error in hibernate named query

Tags: hibernate

```
@NamedQuery(name="getHeightByTaskId",query="select otherheight from BTSTaskDetail where id=2 for update")
```

Error

> ERROR internal.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000177: Error in named query:
>   getHeightByTaskId org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: for near line 1, column 79 [select otherheight from
>   com.inn.siteforge2.bts.model.BTSTaskDetail where id=2 for update]

Answer (score 0):

`for update` is not valid JPQL keyword

For locking use one of standard ways: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking

Comment: what is the alternative for the select for update in hibernate

Comment: Select whole entity, make changes, and call merge()

Answer (score 0):

```
@NamedQuery(name = "BTSTaskDetail.otherheight", query = "SELECT c FROM BTSTaskDetail c WHERE c.otherheight = :otherheight"),
```

now update your entity and save them.

Comment: I know this will work. But actual problem is multiple threads are increment  height value at the same time.For example at one time height value is 4 and 5 threads are simultaneously read the vale from db and increment it by one and update in db  final result is 5 that should be  9.This problem is solved by select for update query that is working fine in mysql. When we use select for update it locks particular row when we read the data and unlock it when data is being committed

Comment: @AnkitPatwa what kind of locking are you using?

Comment: I am using hibernate framework and spring transaction management.Hibernate internally manage the locking.

Comment: you need to declare the bean or facade as @Singleton scope of session. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
@NamedQuery(name="getHeightByTaskId",query="select otherheight from BTSTaskDetail where id=2",lockMode = PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
```

?